# Стих и стихи

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

Скажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли употреблять слово "стих" по отношению к стихотворению: "Я тебе прочитаю свой стих"? Или все-таки "стихи" или "стихотворение"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сперва разберёмся что такое стихотворение. Стихотворение - это творение из стихов. *Стих* в данном случае выступает в своём основном значении, ритмическая единица ритмизованной, стихотворной речи, содержащая определенное число стоп, строка.

*Всё повторяю первый стих

И всё переправляю слово:

- **"Я стол накрыл на шестерых"**...

Ты одного забыл - седьмого.*

Соответственно, так как стихотворения состоят из множества стихов, то  слово **стихи**, находясь во множественном числе вполне может служить синонимом стихотворений. Поэтому стихотворный сборник вполне можно назвать сборником стихов, но нельзя - стиховым.

Стих в единственном числе тоже порой употребляют для обозначения целого стихотворного произведения. В частности у Маяковского:

*Эх,

   поговорить бы иначе

с этим самым

            с Леонидом Лоэнгринычем!

Встать бы здесь

               гремящим скандалистом:

- Не позволю

             мямлить стих

                         и мять!*

Но всё-таки по-прежнему это значение, признаётся большинством словарей как разговорное или просторечное, см. [Ушаков](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1043514), [Ожегов и Шведова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/278805) или вообще не признают значения цельное стихотворение у слова *стих* [Ефремова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/250391/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B8), [Чудинов](http://www.inslov.ru/html-komlev/s/stih.html)

В общем, я бы не рекомендовал использовать слово стих, для обозначение цельного поэтического произведения.

Answer (score 6):

[Стих | ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85)

Стих - термин, используемый в нескольких значениях:

- художественная речь, организованная делением на ритмически соизмеримые отрезки; поэзия в узком смысле; в частности, подразумевает свойства стихосложения той или иной традиции («античный стих», «стих Ахматовой» и т. п.);
- строка стихотворного текста, организованная по определённому ритмическому образцу («Мой дядя самых честных правил»).

Таким образом, в литературе "стих" - это одна строчка стихотворения.ДВУСТИШИЕ (дистих) - вид строфы из двух стихов, ТРЁХСТИШИЕ (терцет) - простая строфа из трёх стихов. ЧЕТВЕРОСТИШИЕ (катрен) – простая строфа из 4 стихов.

Стихом иногда называют короткую строфу, стихотворный абзац произведения(В Библии, например).
Синонимом стихотворения является форма во множ. ч. - стихи, а стих - только разговорное, как и стишок.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно и "стих".
Стих (стишок) в разговорной речи вполне может использоваться в значении стихотворение.

Сомнения возникают по причине того, что обычно в этом значении стихи используются во множественном числе.

СТИХ, -а; м. [греч. stichos - ряд, строка]
...
~2.
обычно мн.: стихи, -ов.
Художественное произведение (произведения) с ритмизованной речью, с определённым размером; стихотворение. Читать стихи. Лирические стихи. Стихи М.Ю.Лермонтова. Сборник стихов. Александрийский с.

(БТС).